# Storing, retrieving and re-constructing paths in the database

Tags: php, mysql

This question relates to creating a path or URL from a fragment stored in MySQL.

Consider the following:

I have a file located in the file system at the following path:
/application/path/to/file

The PHP application has a constant the represents the FS path to the application:
APP_PATH = /application/path/to

In the database the entry for the file has a column with paths:

```
fileId:    path:
1          "file"
```

What is the best way to re-construct the full path to the file in the FS?

Given that I don't want to store the absolute path to the file in the database (in case I change the location e.g. if I change hosting provider etc).

Given that I don't want to have to process the query results in PHP (it's possible that there could be thousands of results and looping through them to prepend the APP_PATH would be time consuming).

Is there perhaps some change I could make to my MySQL statement?

An example query would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepend it as part of the query

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT('" . APP_PATH . "', filename) FROM files"
```

This would be inside PHP, but you can replace the first argument of `CONCAT` with anything.  If you know `APP_PATH` ahead of time you can just type it out.